# Обтекание ImageView несколькими textView

Tags: android, xml

Надо сделать вот такую тему. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать обтекание картинки одним textView - знаю, а вот двумя - нет.
Обтекание одной реализую `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"` в `<TextView`.
Существуют ли ещё методы реализации данного обтекания?

Comment: это не *обтекание*, если надо так, как на картинке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/pic"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="123"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="123"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```